# a href doesn't work on iPhones when tapped

Tags: html, jquery, iphone

I have a dynamically created `<a>` tags:

```
$(".categoryChoice").hover(
   (eventObj)=>{
      id = eventObj.target.id
      $("#subCategories").empty()
         if(id === "clothing") {
            $("#subCategories").append(`<div id="col1" class="col-6" style="border-right: 1px solid grey"></div>`)
            $("#subCategories").append(`<div id="col2" class="col-6"></div>`)
            clothing.map((val,i)=>{
              $("#col1").append(`<a class="subCat nav-link" href="products/featured.html?type=clothing&subType=${val.replace(/\s/g, '')}">${val.toUpperCase()}</a>`)
            })
         }
         ...
   }
)
```

They work on android devices when I tap on the link and across all browsers, but not on iPhones.
When I try to tap on the link it won't do anything, but it only works when i press it for longer. I don't understand the behaviour.

I've checked similar questions and tried putting `target="_self"`in the tag as well, but it wouldn't change anything.

I'm kinda stuck here. I thought of creating a function instead that would get me to desired page, but if there is any simpler way of fixing it, that would be great.

Comment: I tried it with the function so instead:
`function test(route){ window.location.href = route }`
`<li onclick="test("products/.../...")"`
Once again, works perfectly on all devices except iPhone :/

Comment: Ok now it works. I just added `ontouchstart` and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `a` tag I changed it to `li` with function that fires when `onclick` and `ontouchstart` and sends the user to the page. It works well on iphone now.